# Can I create an extension method for System namespace and add it to the GAC?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, gac, class-library

In principle, can I create a class library to store my Extension methods for `System namespace` for example, and add it to the GAC to be usable from any project in my development machine and able to deployment on the GAC of other machines by the setup project ?

If yes, Do you think it useful?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can create an extension method and put it in a class defined in the `System` namespace and then deploy the assembly in the GAC. Other projects could reference the assembly from the GAC and use the extension method.

> Do you think it useful?

Personally I hate the GAC and never use it for custom assemblies. I always prefer applications to be self contained but for people who use it, it could be nice.